# Hadoop: where does jobclient work?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Where does the jobclient work? two situation:

1. copy the job.jar to hdfs, and run the job with "hadoop jar job.jar", i think the jobclient runs on the computer where the command execute, is it right?  can we use this command run a job at a computer off the cluster with jobtracker and hdfs port configured?
2. when i remote programming with eclipse on my computer, run the job with menu"Run on hadoop", does the jobclient run on my computer which is not belong to the cluster? or somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

JobClient is called in the driver class to start the execution of the MR job and a couple of other things. JobClient and Driver are executed on the same node. More details about the JobClient [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html).

Where JobClient runs depends on where the driver is run. The driver can be run from outside or inside of the Hadoop cluster. The driver can be run from a Hadoop cluster gateway also.